# fluidsynth library file compilation to .so file in android

Tags: android

I am trying to compile the files from https://bitbucket.org/kunstmusik/fluidsynth-android to .so file.  The files from this site are .c and .h which have the include files. I have installed ndk, configured it.

1. I have created a new project in eclipse
2. created the jni folder and copied the files from the web site to this folder
3. in command prompt in the jni folder,  I issued the command ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk.  This ran without error

In the /obj/local/ folder, files were created with .o and .d in the fluidsynth-andriod folder.  There is also a .a file in armeabi and aremabi-v7a.  I assume the .a is a static library.  Do I need to create a .so file? Do i need to link the c/c++ to java.  If so how do I do this.

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this same issue myself. The Android.mk file included in the fluidsynth-android code contains the line

```
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

This is what causes the .a files to be generated.

If you change this to

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

you will get .so files instead of .a files.